# combine the results of two queries with different group by clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, heidisql

I have a use case where I want to calculate the number of dates which had stocks in and out. My tbl schema has just 4 cols : stock_type, in_date, out_date, serial_no.

| stck_typ | in_date | out_date | serial_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-18 | 103 |
| S3 | 2022-11-13 | 2022-11-25 | 104 |
| S2 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-07 | 102 |

tbl structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPUpw.png)

Is there a way to get the output like below tbl:

| date | in_count | out_count | stock_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-10 | 3 | 0 | S1 |
| 2022-12-01 | 6 | 0 | S2 |
| 2022-12-01 | 6 | 0 | S1 |
| 2022-12-01 | 6 | 0 | S3 |
| 2022-12-05 | 0 | 8 | S1 |
| 2022-12-05 | 0 | 8 | S2 |

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried the below query on heidisql :
For IN_DATE:

```sql
SELECT in_date, stock_type, COUNT(in_date) AS IN_COUNT FROM records GROUP BY IN_DATE having in_date>='2022-11-10' AND in_date<='2022-12-08'
```

For OUT_DATE:

```sql
SELECT out_date, stock_type,  COUNT(OUT_date) AS OUT_COUNT FROM records GROUP BY OUT_DATE having out_date>='2022-11-10' AND out_date<='2022-12-08'
```

or something like this on bigquery:

```
SELECT in_date,
    a.stock_type,
    count(in_date) OVER(PARTITION BY in_date)
FROM table 

SELECT in_date,
    a.stock_type,
    count(in_date) OVER(PARTITION BY in_date)
FROM table
```

the output looks correct but I want the output in a single query but grouping by on both in_date and out_date is not giving the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider another option not using *UNION* as well,

```sql
SELECT date, stock_type, COUNTIF(offset = 0) in_count, COUNTIF(offset = 1) out_count
  FROM records, UNNEST([in_date, out_date]) date WITH offset
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-11-10' AND '2022-12-08'
 GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: thanks jay for the solution. but how can we achieve the same in sql as few functions of bq won't work there?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ? If it doesn't support *array* type, Dimi's answer has 
more chance that his query works there since it uses a standard  SQL syntax.

Comment: Its HeidiSQL. I want the results of two rows ina single row like yours for out_date and in_date.

Comment: From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/heidisql/ , *HeidiSQL is a Windows client for MariaDB and MySQL.* .  HeidiSQL seems not a DBMS and you seems to use use MariaDB or MySQL.  Then prefer to use Dimi's answer since my answer is for Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to combine two queries for IN and OUT dates:

```
WITH combined AS
(
SELECT in_date AS _date,
       COUNT(in_date) AS IN_COUNT,
       0 AS OUT_COUNT
       stock_type, 
FROM records 
GROUP BY in_date, 
         stock_type

UNION ALL

SELECT out_date,
       0 AS IN_COUNT
       COUNT(out_date) AS OUT_COUNT,
       stock_type, 
FROM records 
GROUP BY out_date, 
         stock_type

)

SELECT _date,
       SUM(IN_COUNT) AS IN_COUNT,
       SUM(OUT_COUNT) AS OUT_COUNT,
       stock_type
FROM combined
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2022-11-10' AND '2022-12-08' -- filtering date range
GROUP BY _date,
         stock_type
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Even I tried this last night but ultimately realized, I need the solution which Jay provided below. Just wanted to check, since sql doesn't have those functions, how can we achieve that?